# Recursively modify all fields in an object annotated with a given annotation

Tags: java, recursion, reflection

Given an input object, I need to find all fields in it with a given annotation and modify it with some value.

This annotation could also be present in an object present inside the given input object.

```
public class A {
  private B b;

  @MyAnnotation
  private String s;

}

public class B {

    @MyAnnotation
    private String a;

    private String b;
}
```

Output, in this case, should be fields s and a and I need to modify the same with some String. I found fieldUtils from apache which gives annotation on a given class, and I think I can add a simple DFS search to find all fields with the given annotation. The problem comes while setting the value using reflection, I need to specify the object as part of `field.set()`. I'm not sure which object should be used while setting the value of a and how to get that in a generic manner (in case I need to retrieve instance of `B` from `A` in this example)

Answer (score 3):

To *recursively modify all fields in an object annotated with a given annotation* we have to determine first *all fields*.

`Class.getFields()` will return only "*accessible public fields*". This doesn't match the requirement. Therefore we have to use `Class.getDeclaredFields()`. This in turn returns only the fields "*declared by the class*". In order to get *all fields* we have to traverse the type hierarchy of a target object upwards and process for each type its declared fields.

For every field we have to distinguish some cases:

1. A `Field` **is** annotated with the specified annotation. Then the given value has to be applied to the field. In order to set the value, the field has to be (made) accessible and non final.
2. A `Field` **is not** annotated with the specified annotation. Then there are three cases to distinguish:

   - The field has a primitive type. Then it isn't an object, which could contain a `String` field.
   - The field has an array type. Then it cannot contain a `String` field.
   - Else: The field has a reference type. Then it has to be (made) accessible, to check if it has a value set and in this case to process its fields recursively for 1) and 2) again.

To check whether an annotation is set on a field, we use `Field.getAnnotation(myAnnotationClass)` where `myAnnotationClass` is declared as `Class<MyAnnotation>`. But we have to be aware of something additional:
`Field.getAnnotation(myAnnotationClass)` will return the fields's annotation **only** if

- it's set (quite self-explanatory)
- `MyAnnotation` itself is annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.

The corresponding code would look like that:

```
  public static <T extends Annotation> void setValueOnAnnotatedFields(String s, Class<T> annotationClass, Object target) {
    if (target != null) {
      // traversing the type hierarchy upward to process fields declared in classes target's class extends
      Class<?> clazz = target.getClass();
      do {
        setValueOnAnnotatedDeclaredFields(s, annotationClass, target, clazz);
      }
      while ((clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) != null);
    }
  }

  private static <T extends Annotation> void setValueOnAnnotatedDeclaredFields(String s, Class<T> annotationClass, Object target, Class<?> clazz) {
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
      if (field.getAnnotation(annotationClass) != null) {
        set(field, target, s);
      } else if (!field.getType().isPrimitive() && !field.getType().isArray()) {
        setValueOnAnnotatedFields(s, annotationClass, get(field, target));
      }
    }
  }

  protected static void set(Field field, Object target, String value) {
    try {
      makeFiieldAccessibleNotFinal(field, target);
      field.set(target, value);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      String message = String.format("Failed to set the value on field %s", target.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + field.getName());
      throw new IllegalStateException(message, e);
    }
  }

  protected static Object get(Field field, Object target) {
    try {
      makeFiieldAccessibleNotFinal(field, target);
      return field.get(target);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      String message = String.format("Failed to get the value on field %s", target.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + field.getName());
      throw new IllegalStateException(message, e);
    }
  }

  protected static void makeFiieldAccessibleNotFinal(Field field, Object target) {
    try {
      Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
      modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
      modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      String message = String.format("Failed to remove final declaration of field %s", field.getName());
      throw new IllegalStateException(message, e);
    }
    try {
      field.setAccessible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      String message = String.format("Failed to make field %s accessible", field.getName());
      throw new IllegalStateException(message, e);
    }
  }
```

An example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a); // s: null / b: [null]

    setValueOnAnnotatedFields("1", MyAnnotation.class, a);
    System.out.println(a); // s: 1 / b: [null]

    a.b = new B();
    setValueOnAnnotatedFields("2", MyAnnotation.class, a);
    System.out.println(a); // s: 2 / b: [a: 2 / b: null]
  }
```

This implies class `A` to have `toString()` implemented like that:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "s: " + s + " / b: [" + Optional.ofNullable(b).map(B::toString).orElse("null") + "]";
}
```

And class `B` to have `toString()` implemented like that:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "a: " + a + " / b: " + b;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer as it didn't _modify all fields in an object_ but only the fields declared by the class of the object. Now it is traversing the type hierarchy upwards to process _all_ fields.

Comment: This does not work with ArraList<ReferenceType>

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java reflection API to inspect the fields of your class:

Get the declared annotations foreach field;

Check if you have your annotation..

Well, it is not a difficult thing to do thanks to Reflection API.

Comment: Getting fields is not a problem, I'm not sure how to set values for the nested fields

Answer (score 0):

You can have some marker annotation on the fields that have to be drilled down. Bean Validation uses a similar approach.

In the following `Bar` is nested into `Foo` and it is annotated with `DrillDown` so as to indicate it has to be drilled into, to find for fields to update.

```
class Foo {
  @Updateable String a;
  @DrillDown Bar bar;
  String c;
}

class Bar {
  @Updateable String b;
}
```

A quick example code that demonstrates it,

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.a = "a-old";
    foo.c = "non-updateable";
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.b = "b-old";
    foo.bar = bar;

    update("new-value", foo);

    System.out.println(foo.a);
    System.out.println(foo.bar.b);
    System.out.println(foo.c);
  }

  public static void update(String value, Object obj) throws Exception {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Updateable updateable = field.getAnnotation(Updateable.class);
      if (updateable != null) {
        field.set(obj, value);
      } else {
        DrillDown drillDown = field.getAnnotation(DrillDown.class);
        if (drillDown != null) {
          update(value, field.get(obj));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Foo {
  @Updateable String a;
  @DrillDown Bar bar;
  String c;
}

class Bar {
  @Updateable String b;
}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface DrillDown {

}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Updateable {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply use Apache commons beanutils' `FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation()`, see
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#getFieldsListWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-

e.g.

```
List<Field> fields = FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(MyBean.getClass(), MyAnnotation.class);
```

You can then further inspect and manipulate the returned fields with all metainfo like other Annotations, if you want to further refine / react on them.